# Display the same color for all characters in a math section

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-tex, plugin-vimtex

In a tex file, almost all the characters inside delimiters like `$...$` or `\[...\]` have the same color, but there are some characters, like `=` (and possibly others) which have a different color. I would like to change the syntax so that everything inside math delimiters has the same color. For example, in the picture below, I would like the `=` sign to be cyan like the other characters.

[image]

I have looked at the `syntax\tex.vim` file but haven't been able to find the proper highlighting setting. I also have vimtex, but I assume it doesn't have the syntax I want by default.

Comment: Well, there's `texMathZone` with a letter, and (for me) `=` and `^` are `texMathOper`. Are you using dracula, btw? The equation characters are purple for me, not cyan.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thank you, very helpful! Yes I have your theme but I have tried to tinker with it in my `vimrc`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file under `VIM_RUNTIME_PATH/syntax`, maybe `~/.vim/sytax`

`syntax/tex.vim`

```tex
syn clear texMathOper
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer, but thank you for telling me what the highlight variable is. I have changed it with `autocmd ColorScheme`.